# get file from directory in vue.js component

Tags: vue.js

I tried to render image in my website that made with vue.js

the file i want is here 
**D:\programing\mr_dan\assets\img\bkgds\cheesecloth-herbs-bk.jpg**

and component of vue in
**D:\programing\mr_dan\src\components\Home.vue**

this the code of **home.vue**

```
<div style="background-image:url(../../assets/img/bkgds/cheesecloth-herbs-bk.jpg);">
```

Comment: provide more information. are you using any build tool like webpack or running vue in a static html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue cli's WebPack is probably not parsing that content as an asset. One workaround is to use `require()`:

```
<div :style="'background-image:url(' + require('../../assets/img/bkgds/cheesecloth-herbs-bk.jpg') + ');'">
```

Check a [demo CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/py5v5zr40m?module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue).